# How to manage time for studying after travelling 4 hours daily to work?

Tags: interviewing, time-management, overtime, stress, travel

I'm a 2 years experienced Software Developer in an Indian company. My hours are 9 to 6 but I usually leave the office at 6:30-6:45 pm.

Normally my commute takes 1.5 hours in the morning and 2 hours in the evening. So, I depart from home at 7:30 am and arrive back home 8:45-9:00 pm.

**Problem:**

I am studying for the interview preparation for big product based companies.

But due to this hectic schedule, I don't find much time to study except on weekends. I'm off every Sunday but have to work every other Saturday (1 Saturday in 2).

So, most of the time on weekdays, I usually get tired by working so much that I don't find enough time and energy to study. Sometimes I try to study while traveling but it becomes possible only for 20 minutes or so, because I have to check my mails and other messages also. And I can only study when I get a seat (on the bus/train), but this is rare as it's standing room only most of the time.

**Question:**

So, what strategy should I adopt to prepare for the interviews?

- Should I continue traveling?
- or should I buy a 1BHK (Bedroom+Hall+Kitchen) flat or rent one closer to work?
- or even live as PG (Paying Guest) closer to work?

I tried living as PG at the start of my career but it was not so fruitful because the food quality was really poor there.

Comment: What is a "PG"? Or BHK for that matter.

Comment: You leave the office at 06.30 or 06.45? are you doing the night shift?

Comment: @SolarMike no it's 6:30 pm

Comment: @nvoigt in India, PG means Paying Guest. BHK means Bedroom+Hall+Kitchen.

Comment: @DG then 18.30 is clearer...

Comment: I've proposed some edits to the question (I don't have enough 'rep' to edit directly) that will hopefully make it more widely applicable (as your problem is a known one outside the details of India, paying guest accommodation, etc). Feel free to revert them if you don't agree, but I hope this captures your intent and then hopefully more people will weigh in. For what it's worth "length of commute" vs "acquiring a place nearer work" (whether that's renting, buying, becoming a lodger, hotel rooms, or whatever) is a pretty universal dilemma.

Comment: Is it plausible to study during the commute?

Comment: @P.Hopkinson OP does say "for 20 minutes or so" and not possible when standing.

Answer (score 6):

Since your problem is the commute, look for ways to avoid it/ make it productive. Example:

- stay a place closer to work location
- listen to podcasts, read technical sites etc if travelling via metro etc
- watch technical videos if the traffic conditions permit
- take occasional work from home to avoid commute
- accumulate some leaves, then take personal time off

Since the impact of this commute is delay in hunt, you can also think of

- extending your job search timelines to avoid overextending yourself with over expectations.
- Try to study during any office breaks etc you may get
  -

Comment: My company doesn't permit work from home.

Comment: @DG4 there are other strategies here, you can try those as well.

Comment: You can also try to check if your workplace offers flexi timings. You can start a little early and leave early ( it beats the rush hour traffic and the journey taking 1.5 hours may take only 45 mins if traffic is avoided both ways, so if you start at 7, you may reach about an hour early and hence can leave an hour early).

Comment: @RishiGoel thanks for your suggestion but my workplace doesn't allow flexi timings. If it would have allowed it, then there would be no problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the option of moving closer to work, do it. Commute time have [a huge effect on happiness](https://m.huffpost.com/us/entry/us_59b6ca67e4b0bb893fffffd9).

I have about the same commuting time as you and I hate it. I have spent so much time commuting in my life. Moving to within 15 minutes of my office next week. This gives me 15 more hours of life per week. Never again will I live far from work.

Comment: Make sure you use that time for home, not work...